# Saving Image from Image Control to file in current directory

Tags: c#, wpf, image, controls

I have an Image Control (WPF) called image1 that load an Image when I click on a commandbutton (here is the code about that event). Now what I have to do if I want to copy that image file on the current directory (so the project dir) ?

```
private void commandButton1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = "*.jpg";
        dlg.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {                
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName));   
        }
        // to do
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you run into UAC issues by doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) method. You may get the file name without path from [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
// get file name from full source path (for example)
string targetFileName = Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName);

// copy to relative path, i.e. current directory
File.Copy(dlg.FileName, targetFileName);
```

---

In case your question is about how to save a BitmapSource, you may look at [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619208.aspx).